# TranslateZ performances issue in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I was trying to implement this http://codepen.io/keithclark/pen/JycFw but experienced serious flicks and lag in chrome using mobile.

```
#slide1:before {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-4.jpg");
  transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

After research, I tried to use transform 3d, backface, perspective etc but still experienced laggy scrolling experience.

Answer (score 0):

TransformZ is bound to lag down the device because it forces the device to render it as if it was 3d. I'm not aware on how to fix this but here are some alternatives parallax effects made in Jquery and CSS:

http://andyshora.com/parallax.html

http://www.devfloat.com/jquery-parallax-scrolling-tutorials/

I hope these help you!